# Haml syntax error | Illegal element: classes and ids must have values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```haml
%h3 Regulations

%table.table.table-striped
%thead
%tr
  %th.cls-th-100 Name
  %th.cls-th Title
  %th
  %th
%tbody
- @regulations.each do |regulation|
  %tr
    %td= link_to regulation.name, admin_regulation_path(regulation)
    %td= regulation.title
    %td
      = link_to edit_admin_regulation_path(regulation) do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit
    %td
      = link_to admin_regulation_path(regulation), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-trash
```

i'm trying to comment out glyphicon-edit and glyphicon-trash, but continue getting error  Illegal element: classes and ids must have values.

Comment: you have some random `do` at the end of your second to last line and no closing curly ...

Comment: This code (after adding the missing `}`) doesn’t produce that error.

Comment: for posting purposes; I couldn't add the } curly bracket, so remove the do? removed the do, and it breaks.

Comment: It still doesn’t produce the error you claim.

Comment: @matt - it also reads an error in config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb    call_without_quiet_assets(env).tap do

Comment: @matt - thanks for reaching out; I've been abusing the privilege of stupidity. be well

Comment: Your loop is not indented within `tbody`. You have an empty `tbody`.

Comment: @justin, looks like you have . or # sign, which is HAML markup. You've said about commenting - that's it probably.

Answer (score 0):

Some confusing comments about closing `dos` and missing curlies up there..... One of the points of haml is that you don't need to close your tags (or control statements) - haml does it for you.

To comment in haml you precede the line with `-#`:

```
-# %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-edit
```

This is pure ruby. The dash starts a line of ruby code and the # is the comment sign in ruby.